# Where can I find a blueprint for Sushi?

Tags: starbound

I've been searching for a long time, and I recently got into exploring the variety of recipes and food in starbound, and I discovered that sushi has some of the most beneficial effects available for food considering the effort involved.

Much googling has been fruitless, so I really need to know, where can I find the blueprint for sushi in starbound?

My character is floran if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From everything that I have seen there is no way in the vanilla game to currently unlock sushi, although this can be done with modding like so:

open your mod folder in your starbound folder
First:
Make a new folder for your sushi mod, call it Sushi
[image: make a folder]
Then:
Make a file called player.config and fill it with:

```
{
"__merge" : [],
"defaultBlueprints" : {
"tier1": [
{ "item" : "sushi" } 
]
}
}
```

Then:
Make a file called sushi.modinfo fill it with:

```
{
"name" : "Sushi",
"path" : ".",
"dependencies" : []
}
```

In the end it will look like this inside sushi and the files:
[image: all together now]

Now all I need I need is some avesmingo, rice and wartweed!
[image]

As for legit ways to get this I really looked hard as I'm sure you did too, I love sushi!
There is not one yet, I bet they will add it with some hylotl village updates.

There are a few good mods that add this sort of hylotl stuff but still no sushi blueprint for the recipe I've found.

It's be brought to my attention that it may be learned upon picking up an item--
I searched for this too, and came up empty. I would love to know when they will add it or where it is hiding if it is somewhere!